# What does it mean to be saddled with debt?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I was reading [this article](http://scoopempire.com/marriage-costs-egypt/#.VHiFpm7eatJ.facebook) talking about costs of marriage in Egypt when I read thise sentence in the end of the article:

> but try being happy in the aftermath when you’re ***saddled with debt***.

I used cambridge online dictionary to figure out the meaning but no get no meaning. All I get is that "saddle" means that thing we put on the horse in order to make us feeling ease when we are riding the horse (or the action of doing so)

But What does this expression mean?

Comment: I applaud you for checking a dictionary, telling us what you found, and even including the name of the dictionary you used. These are all good things. The one tidbit of advice I'd like to mention, though, is that it's often a good idea to consult [multiple dictionaries](http://www.onelook.com/?w=saddle&ls=a). That said, many of the dictionaries that do include this verb's definition aren't entirely clear (e.g., AHD says, "To load or burden; encumber"). This is a good question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means you are burdened with debt: you are the horse, and the debt is riding on your back.

It is a very common expression, virtually a cliché. People are constantly said to be "saddled with" debt or a mortgage or a sullen husband or a nagging wife or teenage children.